# Interrogation about Yeoman, Maven and the location of Thymeleaf HTML templates

Tags: eclipse, maven, war, yeoman, thymeleaf

I recently discovered [**Yeoman**](http://yeoman.io/), a tool that greatly facilitates **JS dependency and build lifecycle management**.

Furthermore, I use **Maven** as my **Java** dependency and build tool. I am actually seeking to integrate both tools so that I get the best of both worlds.

It seems the community has put a lot of effort into ***Maven/Yeoman*** integration with various articles such as this one: http://addyosmani.com/blog/making-maven-grunt/ as well as a **yeoman-maven plugin**: https://github.com/trecloux/yeoman-maven-plugin

Last, I use [**Thymeleaf**](http://www.thymeleaf.org/) as my Spring-MVC templating solution.

Assuming the following directory layout (*see yeoman-maven-plugin above*):

```
pom.xml
 - src
   - main
     - java
     - webapp
     - …
   - test
     - ..
 - yo
   package.json
   component.json
   Gruntfile.js
   - app
     index.html
     ...
   - test
     ...
   - dist
     ...
```

My question is **where should my Thymeleaf templates reside**?

1. Under the `yo/app` directory? (they would be subsequently copied into appropriate directory by maven)
2. Directly under the `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/templates` directory?

What I can't figure out in the case of an **AngularJS** application for instance, is when and how templates/pages including server-side content can interact with the servlet container given that Yeoman assumes they live under its `app` directory...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `Thymeleaf` as your [templating engine with Spring](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Thymeleaf-Spring3.html), I assume you have something like

```
  <bean id="templateResolver"
        class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="templateEngine"
        class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
  </bean>

  <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
  </bean>
```

In other words, your templates should reside in the folder specified in the `ServletContextTemplateResolver` property `prefix`. In the above example, that's `/WEB-INF/templates`. These should therefore be in `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/templates`.

If you are not using a `ServletContextTemplateResolver`, but instead using a `ClassLoaderTemplateResolver`, you can put them anywhere on your application classpath and specify it in that bean's properties. There's also a `FileTemplateResolver` in which you can specify an absolute path to anywhere on your file system.

When building the application with Eclipse (maven plugin), having the folders

```
/src
    /main
        /webapp
            /WEB-INF
                /templates
                    /some-template.html
            /index.html
        /java
            /com
                /yourcompany
                    /Main.java
        /resources
            /some-properties.properties
```

maven will generate the following

```
/WEB-INF
    /templates
         /some-template.html
    /index.html
/classes 
    /com
        /yourcompany
             /Main.class
    /some-properties.properties
```

As a expanded `.war` and provide that to your servlet container, ex. Tomcat.

Comment: Hi Sotirios! Your idea to use the `FileTemplateResolver` is very good. I guess I could use it with a **dev** spring profile and stick with the `ServletContextTemplateResolver` in **prod** having the thymeleaf templates in the **yo** directory (in **dev**). Remains the question of how eclipse is going to deal with all that...

Comment: @balteo I don't know how maven builds with `yo`. See my edit for more information on how maven typically does it.